# Comprobación de integridad de Ficheros

Tags: java, seguridad, hash

Buenas, me gustaría comprobar la integridad de un archivo a través de un directorio, es decir, para verificar la integridad de un archivo, sólo hay que comparar el hash del archivo original con el hash del archivo descargado, si ambos son iguales, se puede deducir que el archivo descargado no ha sido alterado y es idéntico al original.

He encontrado el siguiente código por internet:

```
public class Resumenes{

public static void main(String [] args){

//declarar funciones resumen
  try{
  MessageDigest messageDigest2 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA"); // Inicializa SHA-1

  //leer fichero byte a byte

     try{
        InputStream archivo = new FileInputStream( args[0] );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        int fin_archivo = -1;
        int caracter;

        caracter = archivo.read(buffer);

        while( caracter != fin_archivo ) {

           messageDigest2.update(buffer);// Pasa texto claro a la función resumen
           caracter = archivo.read(buffer);
        }   

        archivo.close();
        byte[] resumen2 = messageDigest2.digest(); // Genera el resumen SHA-1

        //Pasar los resumenes a hexadecimal

        String m = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < resumen2.length; i++)
        {
           m += Integer.toHexString((resumen2[i] >> 4) & 0xf);
           m += Integer.toHexString(resumen2[i] & 0xf);
        }
        System.out.println("Resumen SHA-1: " + m);


     }
     //lectura de los datos del fichero
     catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException fnfe) {}
     catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {}

  }   
  //declarar funciones resumen
  catch(java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {}

  }
}
```

Pero claro cuando ejecuto me salta el "Debug" se que no le estoy pasando el directorio, pero esa es mi duda, ¿donde tengo que pasarlo? 
Por ejemplo este es el directorio que quiero pasarle para que me devuelva su código Hash.
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Prueba\SSII\PC1\Hash\Mensaje.txt

Esto lo estoy realizando en Eclipse.

Gracias.

Comment: Te salta el "Debug", cual es exactamente el error?

Comment: Al ejecutar el código en Eclipse me sale la primera captura de pantalla y en lo de debug me sale la siguiente captura, no se a que se debe.        
 Le adjunto un par de imagenes que me salen: https://mega.nz/#!FdUDhL5R!U_RiwxESUpAj0gCxwicQ2nHT9pUcKMM4EkdEBDX6lv8                 https://mega.nz/#!BBs2jCLS!Z03b13NZ7Uv1A6kco0ZW70Pp35QItWvMI6jSHBvuiK8

Comment: He probado también en la ventana de Eclipse de "Console" el directorio que quiero pasarle para que me duelva el hash del contenido, pero no me hace nada y no sé. Haber si me pueden ayudar !!